# Laravel 5.4 View composer con datos de un controlador $request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Llevo mucho tiempo intentado obtener variables para varias vistas. Básicamente lo que necesito es hacer esto:

```
class VarComposers
{

    public function compose(View $view ){

        $user =  '555';

        $view->with('user', $user);
    }

} //class
```

Pero con la data que obtengo acá:

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $client = new Client();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'min:3|max:100', 
    ]);

    $response = $client->post("http://localhost:8000/v1/login", [

        'headers' => ['foo' => 'bar'],
            'json' => [
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'password' => $request['password'],
            ]
    ]);


    $user = json_decode( $response->getBody()->getContents() );

    return view('pages.home', compact('user'));
}
```

No se si me hago entender, pero espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: ¿Intentas devolver una vista pasándole los datos de un usuario obtenidos tras un login? además, con la clase VarComposers, y el método compose, intentas agregarle nuevos datos a esa vista?

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que necesito los datos de usuario en otras vistas. estos datos vienen de un API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mecanismo por el que generas la vista y le envías datos

```
return view( "tu-vista", compact( "datos_x" ));
```

guarda los datos en sesión en un mecanismo interno de Laravel para hacerlos accesibles desde esa vista que vas a cargar.

Si necesitas cargar unos datos para tenerlos disponibles en varias vistas, suponiendo que por ejemplo uses más de un controlador para generarlas, es decir que los vas a propagar por varias partes de la aplicación, puedes crearte una variable de sesión propia y guardarlos ahí. Sólo que no podrás accederlas desde *blade* directamente, como si fueran variables que le pasaste a la vista. Tendrás a acceder a la variable concreta de sesión que te creaste.
Para todo ésto se tira de PHP puro y duro.

Si las vistas se generan en un mismo controlador, teoricamente, puedes usarlo para almacenar esos datos, por ejemplo mediante una propiedad estática, e ir pasándoselos a las vistas según las vas llamando.

Saludos.

Comment: Lo solucioné usando Laravel Session. también vi que se puede mezclar Session con view composer.

Comment: ¿Que versión usas de Laravel, 5.3, 5.4, ...? Podrías añadirlo a tu pregunta. Los mecanismos que estan accesibles en una pueden no estar en otra. Saludos.